# Defaulting parameters to false

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, null

In my rails controllers,  I am consistently using this logic:

```
def report
  dump = params[:dump] ? params[:dump] : 'false'

  data = {}

  if dump != 'false'
    return render :json => p(data)
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to write this?  A ternary operation is just an eyesore.  I thought maybe just using the `||` operator:

```
dump = params[:dump] || false
```

But that doesn't yield the desired result.

How can I better write this?

Comment: Those look like placeholder names, and "this logic" could also imply that you're just showing an example.  We require *real* code that you're working on.

Comment: Not only that, we'd like to see the whole controller method, so that we can understand _why_ you would want to set it to `false`.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.  I don't mind editing questions, but when closing, it'd be nice to have a comment on why so i can improve on my question `:)`

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for your help to make it a better question.

Comment: This is my first code-review question.  I'm a regular on SO.. the "How to ask" seems to be unclear about "masked" variables.  I thought putting masked(renamed) variables would have been fine, but I understand why the context would be important.

Comment: Note that [empty strings are considered true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/885414/1157100) in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear how you are using `dump = false` and whether the method returns anything more than nil when `params[:dump]` is unassigned. If it doesn't, I would recommend the use of a [guard clause](http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2009/02/16/using-guard-clauses-in-your-ruby-code/):

```
def report
  return unless params[:dump]
  data = {}
  render :json => p(data)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [coalesce gem](https://github.com/kibiz0r/coalesce) as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069997/1479211) SO answer.

```
def report
    dump = params[:dump]._? false

    data = {}

    if dump != false
        return render :json => p(data)
    end
end
```

Though I believe it would be more idiomatic to just use the falsyness of `nil` like this:

```
def report
    dump = params[:dump]
    data = {}

    if dump
        return render :json => p(data)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern in Rails, so common that there is a Ruby Objct extension for it called [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence).

> Returns the receiver if it's present otherwise returns nil. object.presence is equivalent to
>
> ```
> object.present? ? object : nil
> ```

In your case, the code will be changed from

```
dump = params[:dump] ? params[:dump] : 'false'
```

to

```
dump = params[:dump].presence || false
```

It's hard to refactor the entire code, because it's not clear what should happen in case the parameter is false. I assume you may want to display an error.

If that's the case, there is also another way: use an exception, or even better, reuse `require` from the Rails [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) feature, which is based on exceptions

```
dump = params.require(:dump)
```

This line alone, will allow you to get rid of the entire body.

```
def report
  dump = params.require(:dump)

  data = {}
  render :json => p(data)
end
```

If the parameter is missing, an exception `ActionController::ParameterMissing` is raised. You can rescue it in the app, and show the proper message.

```
rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :handle_parameter_missing

def handle_parameter_missing(exception)
  # do what you want
end
```

Comment: this looks promising.  i'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Pure ruby is your friend here :

```
dump = params.fetch(:dump, false)
```

see [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) for more info.

**note :** If you get an emtpy string from your params, in this case I usually find it more relevant to change the markup to avoid the need for `.presence` calls. This is a matter of taste ; all things considered, in ruby any object other than nil and false is truthy, so I think it is coherent with ruby's 'spirit' to avoid passing meaningless params at all.